# nodejs + express strange things on different ports

Tags: node.js, express, port, middleware

Can someone tell me what is going on?
I have an aplication:

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http')
  , app = express()
  , port = 3000
  , mw = require('./lib/middlewareView')

app.use(mw());

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.send("hello");
});

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

and /lib/middlewareView.js :

```
module.exports = function middlewareView(){
  return function middlewareView(req, res, next) {
    console.log("middleware run");

    next();
  };
};
```

When I'm using port 3000 and open `http://localhost:3000/` everything seems to be fine.
console output:

```
Listening on 3000
middleware run
hello
```

But if I switch to port 5000, console prints this:

```
Listening on 5000
middleware run
hello
middleware run
middleware run
```

So the middleware runs 3 times during one request, right?
Is it normal?

Comment: @nlsbshtr You are absolutely right, that was `favicon.ico`. Thank you for fast reply.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably to do with favicon.ico - this happens when retrieving the icon for your site, check logs to make sure...